# javascript file is not found

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I'm trying to link a javascript file to an html file using the `<script>` tag.  When rendering the html page, I see an error in the console claiming that the javascript file is not being found.

Below is my project structure:

`

```
Volume serial number is 0E1E-EFCF
C:.
│   file.txt
│   README.md
│
├───html
│       charts.html
│
├───javascript
│       charts.js
│
└───Server
        package-lock.json
        package.json
        server.js
```

`

I'm trying to link the `charts.js` file to the `charts.html` file by doing the following in the charts.html file:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en" dir="ltr">

    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <title></title>
    </head>

    <body>
      <p id="paragraph">This is an example.</p>
      <script src="/../javascript/charts.js"></script>

    </body>

    </html>
```

I am using node.js to render the files, and my server.js file contains all of my routes:

```
//jshint esversion:6

//'importing' express.
const express = require('express');

//importing bodyParser
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');

//importing the request package
const request = require('request');

//importing path for accessing directories in different levels.
var path = require('path');

//specifies that this app will be using express.
const app = express();

//Configure bodyParser before using.
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));

//static AWS EC2 instance server port. Edit with caution.
const serverPort = 5000;

//AWS EC2 instance Base URL for remote access.
const awsEc2InstanceBaseUrl
  = "http://ec2-34-219-122-169.us-west-2.compute.amazonaws.com" + ":" + serverPort;

//Handle all root requests.
app.get("/", function(req, res) {
  res.send("Hello, World!");
});


//THIS IS CAUSING ISSUE(?)
app.get("/charts", function(req, res) {
  res.sendFile( path.resolve(__dirname + "/../html/charts.html"));
});

app.get("/test-api", function(req, res){
  const testApiEndpoint = "https://www.googleapis.com/books/v1/volumes?q=isbn:0747532699";

  //The following few lines documents how to make an API call using javascript
  request(testApiEndpoint, function(error, response, body){
    console.log(body);
    res.sendFile(body);
  });

});

//Start-up behaviour.
app.listen(serverPort, function() {
  console.log("Server started on AWS EC2 instance: " + awsEc2InstanceBaseUrl);
  console.log("You may access the server locally via: http://localhost:" + serverPort);
});
```

I'm assuming the path to the javascript file is relative to the charts.html file. But given that I'm seeing a 404 not found error when rendering, I guess I am wrong.

`Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)`

Where am I going wrong here?

Comment: None of what you've provided shows how you're telling the server to serve the js or html files. Just like with apache, njinx, or anything else used to serve files, you've gotta specify what should be served.

Comment: @KevinB : How does one tell the server how to serve the js or html files?

Comment: Depends. How are you currently serving the html file? Typically... the way this is handled in production is by serving static files using apache or njinx intead of node.js. but in development, it's common to have express or whatever you're using to handle routing serve them.

Comment: Locally via node.js and chrome

Comment: So i assume you have some kind of... res.sendFile for the .html file? you'd need to do something similar for each other file you want to serve, or use whatever methods are available to the api you are using to serve an entire folder.

Comment: I've updated the post to include the server.js file that is routing to each endpoint.  When the /charts endpoint is hit, it returns the charts.html file.  Basically, I don't know how to manipulate the charts.html file (via event listeners for example) using javascript once it gets served.  I'm trying using the charts.js file, but it isn't being found

Comment: So you're going to keep updating your question to provide additional information, but down vote other peoples answers based on an incomplete question? My question addressed the OP's original question, and is the correct answer based on the info presented at the time.

Answer (score -1):

> ```
> <script src="/../javascript/charts.js"></script>
> ```

Since you can't go above the root of the server, this resolves as `/javascript/charts.js`.

So the browser asks the server for that.

It tries to find a route which matches.

> ```
> app.get("/",
> ```

That doesn't match `/javascript/charts.js`.

> ```
> app.get("/charts"
> ```

Nor does that.

… and now the server has run out of routes to test against.

The browser is asking for `/javascript/charts.js` and the server can't find anything for that URL. Hence: 404.

You need to write an endpoint that serves your JS file.

You could follow the pattern you used for `/charts` … but that's bloated and tedious. Use [the static module](https://expressjs.com/en/starter/static-files.html). Use it for any existing endpoint that just does `res.sendFile` too.